# Is it safe to put non-standard units inside racks?

Tags: rack, hardware, rackmount

Is it unsafe or might the request be denied by some companies that offer colocation to put non-standard units inside a full rack?

This is [my case](https://www.bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020140704023505485N5SxDMkW0693) and, speaking of dimensions, it fits.

Also, as you can see, it has two fans on the sides.

Can it be put inside a rack? Would it be safe?

**EDIT:**

By "safe" I mean both physically and thermally speaking

Comment: Is it unsafe in what way? Is it unsafe to hang it by a string? Of course. Please give us some detail on what safety aspects you're referring to. electrical, environmental, etc., etc.

Comment: :) Totally right, updated question! (I hope [those days](http://www.linuxno.de/_data/gallery/nwl7/_medium_DSCN7824.JPG) are gone :) )

Comment: Woah, that picture is scary.

Comment: What's up with people co-locating their Bitcoin mining gear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most colocation companies charge per rack unit, 1 of which is 1.75" high. Some *will* allow you to have a shelf, and if you've purchased enough rack units, allow you to put into the cabinet whatever you please, so long as it's safe and remains within your allocated power consumption. If the box is too heavy for the shelf (unless the shelf bolts at both the front and the back), they will likely refuse to install it.

The fan situation may play against you though. Rack servers are designed to pull cold air in through the front, and vent it out the back. If the fans on this unit are oriented the same way (air pulled in through one end, out through the other), then you will need to ensure they orient the unit correctly in the cabinet to ensure the side that sucks the air in faces the cold aisle.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your prospective hoster. The fans not only on the back will be a major problem though, not only for mechanical reasons but for thermal management as well. Most data centers are planned around hot and cold aisles and the hot air *needs* to get out to the back.

Comment: My guess would be the fans are pushing the air the same direction, front to back.